# Which of the following is fastest in objective-C?

Tags: objective-c

1. @synchronized
2. Explicit locking
3. Condition locking
4. Mutex implicit locking

Comment: For 2-4, you should clarify exactly what you mean, since you've tagged the question ObjC. You mean NSLock, and...? (Also, you're likely to get people telling you "profile them and see" unless you ask for specific considerations)

Comment: @Ben Zotto There is a bug with ISSpinLocks in iOS: http://openradar.appspot.com/23896366
http://mjtsai.com/blog/2015/12/16/osspinlock-is-unsafe/#comment-2543463

Answer (score 3):

Plase, read this [article](http://cocoasamurai.blogspot.com/2008/04/osspinlock-lock-showdown-posix-locks-vs.html), in which the speeds of the methods are compared

OSSpinLock and POSiX Mutex Lock are the fastest

Comment: See my comment on post above - there is a bug with OSSpinLocks on iOS